# POSTFIX only receive email if server hostname is included in email address

Tags: postfix, domain, tls

I have this situation:

postix/sasl/dovecot

I recently added dovecot and sasl and i can only receive email to postfix if i use this email format: user@serverhostname.domain.com

If i use desired format: user@domain.com there is bounce back to originator email address  5.0.0 smtp; 554 5.7.1: Relay access denied

my MX is pointing to domain name

I have only one domain.

```
postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_at_myorigin = yes
append_dot_mydomain = yes
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
masquerade_domains = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname,$mydomain,localhost
mydomain = domain.cz
myhostname = host.domena.cz
mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/28 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname >> is hostname.domain.cz
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = $mydestination
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,permit_auth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Can someone suggest solution?

*Forgot to mention*, difficult part is that there is no record in log. `/var/log/mail.log` and `/var/log/mail.err` are empty. Interesting part is that I can receive email just fine over www.dnsexit.com, but other 3 mail clients including web mail servers does not go trh

Comment: Post relevant maillog when rejection happened

Comment: Forgot to mention, difficult part is that there is no record in log. /var/log/mail.log and /var/log/mail.err are empty. Interesting part is that I can receive email just fine over www.dnsexit.com, but other 3 mail clients including web mail servers does not go trhu

Comment: try setting `myorigin = $mydomain` as format appears to be `user@myorigin.mydomain` I've not tried this but since you are masquerading.. I've nothing more on this.

Comment: tried `myorigin = $mydomain` no effect

Answer (score 1):

Solved by correct MX record setup